# What is the difference between using this.props and props in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been using `this.props` and `props` interchangeably, and for the most part, there doesn't seem to be a major difference between them (as far as I can tell).

However, I've been running into issues lately that make me think that when and why one is used over the other matters.

This is where I'm currently using them interchangeably:

```
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.data    = props.card.data;
    this.dataLength = this.props.card.data.length;
  }
```

What's the difference and when do you use one over the other, and where? 
Thanks!

Comment: can you show one example when you are using this.props and props interchangeably?

Comment: Could you show an example where you would say `this.props` is different from `props`?

Comment: I updated the question to include it

Comment: you can use props because you are inside a constructor and props are passed in as an argument. When outside of constructor you would need to refer to the instance (this) to access it's props

Comment: If the props are passed to the function you can use directly "props", if not use "this.props".

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on the type of component you are using.

```
const StatelessComponent = (props) => {
    return <div>{props.something}</div>;
}

class SomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.something}</div>;
    }
}
```

Here you will notice that in the stateless component it is just a regular function without any `this` context. The props are passed to the function so we already have access to it.
When you have a class you have a `this` context that the props live on.
In the constructor of a class the props are passed to the class constructor. So in the context of that constructor function props is passed as an argument and is a local variable

**I would recommend** you stick to a pattern, when you have props passed as an argument to a function you use `props` when you are in other methods of a react class you use `this.props`. That is how it was intended to be used. Also there is something to be said for consistency, so whether you choose one or the other stick with that pattern. It can be confusing if you don't follow a pattern / keep things consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Only in the `constructor` of React ES2015 components (non-function components) will you be able to refer to `props` as it is passed into the constructor. If you do `this.props === props` in the `constructor`, it will evaluate to `true`.

However in React, you can only use `this.props` after you call `super(props)`. This is part of the [ES2015 Class spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).

For simplicity, I usually just use solely `props` within the `constructor`, and `this.props` within the component lifecycle methods and in `render`.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms:

- > 1.props.data is used in functional components
  >   2.this.props.data is used in Class components

copy the code and run it in "stackblitz" ->https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3wr8jb

the following code shows usage of both class and functional components with props.data and this.props.data

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

//=================PROPS=======================
//Both Class and Functional components have "properties" ie props
//properties are immutable->fixed->cant be changed

//=================================================
//props.data in functional components
function A1(props)
{
  return <h2>functional component->props.data:{props.data}</h2>
}
//===============================================
//this.props.data in class components
class A2 extends React.Component{
  render()
  {
    return<h2>class component->this.props.data:{this.props.data}</h2>
  }
}
//===================================================
var element1=
<div>
<hr/>
//data from class and functional component
<A1 data="Sample data" />
<A2 data="Sample data"></A2>
<hr />
</div>


render(element1, document.getElementById('root'));
```